# Why is Futaba's nickname "Teko"?

Tags: japanese-language, amanchu

In Episode 1 of *Amanchu!*, Hikari bestows the nickname "Teko" on Futaba, with the following explanation.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> **Hikari**: [Gazes longingly into Futaba's eyes]
>
> **Hikari**: Wow! Your eyebrows are so thin. They're, like, one-tenth as thick as the average. One-tenth...Tenth...Teko! An adorable nickname!

How did Hikari hit upon this nickname in the original Japanese? And bonus question: the translation I read of the manga translated Futaba's nickname as "Dotty". Was this completely out of nowhere, or does it have some justification in the original?

Comment: It's probably a short form of some word that has a "te" sound somewhere at the beginning sticked together with "ko" which means "child" and is commonly used in such nickname portmanteaus. Try listening to what the characters are saying in that scene and you'll probably hear a "te" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Japanese, Hikari says that Futaba's eyebrows look like *tenten*, the two strokes added to a kana to change the voicing value, also known as *dakuten*. E.g. か *ka* becomes が *ga*.

You can see the resemblance in this picture from the manga, at least if you imagine Futaba's eyebrows both pointing in the same direction:

[image]

[image]

"Dotty" came from a translation of *tenten* as "dot", presumably because "Periody" or "Semicolony" didn't sound good.

Comment: So Teko is from Tenten no Ko (〃の子 or tenten girl)?

Comment: @AyaseEri I assume so. In the scene it seems like Hikari skips straight from tenten to Teko but I don't know where else "ko" could have come from.